# SQL Server Query Performance - Normal Join vs Subquery

Tags: join, subquery

I have two queries that return the same data.

Query1, which is normal join takes a long time to execute:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 bigtable.*, tbl1.name, tb2.name FROM 
bigtable INNER JOIN tbl1 on bigtable.id1 = tbl1.id1 AND 
INNER JOIN tbl2 on tbl1.id1 = tbl2.id1
```

order by bigtable.id desc

Query2 that uses a sub-query returns fairly quickly:

```
SELECT subtable.*, tbl1.name, tb2.name FROM 
(SELECT TOP 1000 FROM bigtable) subtable
INNER JOIN tbl1 on subtable.id1 = tbl1.id1 AND 
INNER JOIN tbl2 on tbl1.id1 = tbl2.id1
order by subtable.id desc
```

bigtable contains 100k rows or so. tbl1 is a very small table (less than 10 rows). I would rather not use subqueries. If I skip the order by clause, both queries run quickly. I have tried adding indexes to the fields being joined, adding a DESC index on id etc. but nothing seems to help.

Any help is appreciated!

===> Update:

This turned out to be an non-issue. After creating another table similar to tbl1 with the same rows, I found that the Query1 ran under a second (with the copied table). Rebuilt stats on tbl1 and it fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the two queries are not equivalent - try to write the second one as

```
SELECT subtable.*, tbl1.name, tb2.name FROM 
(SELECT TOP 1000 FROM bigtable order by bigtable.id desc) subtable
INNER JOIN tbl1 on subtable.id1 = tbl1.id1 AND 
INNER JOIN tbl2 on tbl1.id1 = tbl2.id1
order by subtable.id desc
```

I expect the expensive operation to be the ordering of the big table, which is now present in both versions.

Comment: I am trying to make the first one faster (i.e. I am not trying to optimize the subquery).

Comment: But you have missed the fact the two queries are not actually equivalent: The first one selects the top 1000 records **after** ordering 100k records, this is the reason why it is more expensive. The second one, as you wrote it, selects the top 1000 records from the big table **without ordering**, which is of course a very cheap operation, then joins the result with the small table, then orders 1000 records.

I rewrote the subquery not to optimise it, but to make it equivalent to the first query. If I am correct, then you should compare your JOIN performance with the corrected subquery.

Comment: By the way I found a typo in my post, the subquery should contain the clause "order by bigtable.id", not "order by subtable.id". I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. It turned out that the reason for performance degradation was outdated stats on bigtable and tbl1 (small table). After rebuilt them, the data returned in less than a second (on the first query without the subquery).